# How to create a File object with a String

Tags: java

[image]

In my TestClass I want to read the txt-file. I am always very confused how I should go about getting a reference to the txt-file though. The example I dug out of the internet suggested using a BufferedReader which requires a Path object to instantiate. I thought I'd create a File object and invoke it's .toPath(). But now how do I instantiate my File object? The least scary of its constructors require a string, but which string?

Comment: `File file = new File(path in which your .txt it's stored)`

Comment: @Error404 How do I find that path?

Comment: Go to the folder in which you have stored your .txt. In your case, inside the folder of `Eclipse > java > JavaProjectTest > src` and look if there is there. If not, look if there is a folder named `test` and if the .txt it's inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to reference the file path within the scope of your project would be to use the System properties. Using the below value would return to you the users current working directory. Something like this would do the trick:

```
File file = new File (System.getProperty ("user.dir") + "/" + path_to_txt_file);
```

Depending on your system you may need to modify the delimiter.